# Scala chaining functions when Some without explicit checks

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm trying to find a proper way of executing chained functions, as long as Some is returned. Returning None should stop executing further. I believe there must be a way of doing it without checks inside each of the function. A simple example what I meant:

```
  def a(x: Int): Option[Int] = {
    println(x)
    Some(x+1)
  }

  def stop(x: Int): Option[Int] = {
    println(x)
    None
  }

  a(1)
    .map(a)
    .map(a)
    .map(a)
    .map(stop)
    //Do not execute further
    .map(a)
    .map(a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `flatMap`

```
a(1)
.flatMap(a)
.flatMap(stop)
//Do not execute further
.flatMap(a)
.flatMap(a)
```

In this example `a` will be invoked only twice.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. Need to read more about flatMap though, I thought it's just for "flatting" solution when mapping nested collections

Comment: You do flatting it in some sense. You turn `Option[Option[Int]]` into `Option[Int]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for` to chain `map` and `flatMap` calls in a way that is easy to read:

```
for {
  a1 <- a(1)
  a2 <- a(a1)
  a3 <- stop(a2)
  a4 <- a(a3)
  a5 <- a(a4)
} yield a5
```

If all calls return `Some` then the result is `Some(a5)`, but if any call returns `None` then processing will stop and the result will be `None`. So in this case, it will stop after `stop` is called and return `None`.

Using `for` allows you to use a meaningful name for the intermediate results, making the code easier to understand.